# Excel API Call looping help needed

Tags: excel, powerquery

i can pull the standard api information and display it in a table with the information i require.

How ever this only pulls 100 entries and there are several thousand to pull, is there a way to loop this in excel to pull all the results.

https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=log&log=8395,8396&comment=TornAPI&key=fullaccesskeyhere

in excels api advanced editor after selecting the tables i want i get this

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=log&log=8395,8396&comment=TornAPI&key=keyhere")),
    log = Source[log],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(log),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"log", "title", "timestamp", "category", "data"}, {"Value.log", "Value.title", "Value.timestamp", "Value.category", "Value.data"}),
    #"Expanded Value.data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value.data", {"opponent", "pot"}, {"Value.data.opponent", "Value.data.pot"})
in
#"Expanded Value.data"
```

this will pull the information and store it in the table, is there a way of modifying the link to loop it?

is this possible using the normal api or is there some vb script or something i must do?

Comment: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: i watched this video and get how it should work..but it doesnt with this api just feeds back error

Comment: ok so what i have figured out is thje Offset as it were would be a unix timestamp so

https://api.torn.com/user/?selections=log&log=8395,8396&from=1572480000&to=1572652799&key=apikey here 

would show that days could i use the offset function like in that video to change both the from and to time by 86400 seconds to do another call?